# Parsing Netsh output

Tags: windows, powershell, parsing

I need to parse the output given by the netsh command in powershell.
Below is the command i'm using

```
Netsh advfirewall show private
```

It's proving the below output

```
Private Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096
```

My requirement is to access each and every value in the above output. Something like $result.state / $result.InboundUserNotification

I'm pretty new to PowerShell and i have searched on google about this and wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Have you tried to use the "Get-NetFirewallProfile Private"? This does the thing in all current windows versions.

Comment: I have tried this. But there's an issse with Get-NetFirewallProfile. You can refer this [link](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/problem-with-get-netfirewallprofile/)



Netsh is giving me the current settings on the local computer

Comment: I don't know about this specific cmdlet but in general `netsh` is considered deprecated and powershell cmdlets should be preferred in case of conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obligatory recommendation:

- It's always better to find a *PowerShell* cmdlet to call, so you can take advantage of *objects* getting output, whose properties you can robustly access - but it sounds like the candidate cmdlet, [`Get-NetFirewallProfile` doesn't work as expected for your use case](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/problem-with-get-netfirewallprofile/) (domain-joined computers).

*Text* parsing is always less robust than an object-based solution, though PowerShell offers many powerful features, if needed, notably in this case the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with its `-Regex` option:

```
$result = [ordered] @{}  # initialize the (ordered) result hashtable.

# Process each line output by netsh, and if it is a line 
# containing a property/value-pair, add an entry to the hashtable.
switch -Regex (netsh advfirewall show private)  {
  '^(.+?) {2,}(.+)' { $result[$Matches.1] = $Matches.2 }
}

# Now you can access $result.State, $result.'Firewall Policy', ...
```

Note the **assumption that the property name and its value are separated by at least *two* spaces**
( `{2,}`); lines that don't match the property/value pattern are simply skipped.

---

An **alternative is to assume a *fixed column width*** with a single space separating the columns, which does seem to be the case here:

```
$result = [ordered] @{}  # initialize the (ordered) result hashtable.

# Process each line output by netsh, and if it is a line 
# containing a property/value-pair, add an entry to the hashtable.
switch -Regex (netsh advfirewall show private)  {
  '^(.{37}) (.+)' { $result[($Matches.1).TrimEnd()] = $Matches.2 }
}
```

<sup>Note the `(...)` (parentheses) around `$Matches.1`, which is unexpectedly required in order to call `.TrimEnd()` on the value; the parentheses wouldn't be necessary if *index syntax* (`[1]`) rather than *property syntax* `.1` were used (that is, `$Matches[1].TrimEnd()` would work). The problem seems to be specific to property / key names that are *numbers*. See [GitHub issue #14036](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14036)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you must parse this output, you can do the following:

```
$netsh = (Netsh advfirewall show private |
    Select-String -Pattern "\s{2,}") -replace '\s{2,}','=' -replace '\\','\\' -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
$result = [pscustomobject](ConvertFrom-StringData $netsh)
```

The problem with the `ConvertFrom-StringData` method is the hash table output is not ordered. If order matters, you can just create your hash table by splitting each line into property/value pairs:

```
$hash = [ordered]@{}
Netsh advfirewall show private | Select-String -Pattern "\s{2,}" |
    Foreach-Object {
         $key,$value = $_ -split '\s{2,}'
         $hash[$key] = $value
    }
$result = [pscustomobject]$hash
```

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar approach to [AdminOfThings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789686/4085331) utilizing `ConvertFrom-StringData` as well as `Foreach-Object`'s `-Begin` and `-End` parameters.

```
Netsh advfirewall show private |
     ForEach-Object -Begin{$ht = [ordered]@{}} {
        if($_ -match '\s{10,}')
        {
            $ht += $_ -replace '\\','\\' -replace '\s{10,}','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
        }
    } -End{[PSCustomObject]$ht} -OutVariable result
```

And a slight variation

```
Netsh advfirewall show private | Where-Object {$_ -match '\s{10,}'} |
     ForEach-Object -Begin{$ht = [ordered]@{}} {
        $ht += $_ -replace '\\','\\' -replace '\s{10,}','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
    } -End{[PSCustomObject]$ht} -OutVariable result
```